# Formula for marginal probability in CRF++

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-probability

On the website for CRF++ http://crfpp.sourceforge.net/
they mention that marginal probabilities can be output for each possible label.
My question is, in CRF theory, what's the formula for this marginal probability? I think it's:

$$p_{_\theta}(Y_{_j} = y | X ) = \frac{\alpha_{_j}(y|X)\beta_{_j}(y|X)}{Z_{_\theta}(X)}$$

where Yj is a sebsequence of Y, which is the sequence of labels, conditioned on the observed variable X, and Z(X) is a normalization function of X, and α and β are the forward and backward probabilities used in forward-backward algorithms.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

According to *An introduction to conditional random fields*[1](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/csutton/publications/crftut-fnt.pdf) the marginal distribution in (4.20) is:

$p(y_t|x) = \frac{1}{Z(x)} \alpha_t(y_t) \beta_t(y_t)$ (p. 318).

The normalization function of X, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are identical to what you mention. We can of course rewrite this to:

$p(y_t|x) = \frac{\alpha_t(y_t) \beta_t(y_t)}{Z(x)}$

Whether or not to include the $\theta$ and to use $X$ or $x$ seem like notation preferences. $y_t$ is a shorthand for $Y_t = y$ (p. 273), [2](https://www.coursera.org/learn/probabilistic-graphical-models-3-learning/lecture/m2r5h/maximum-likelihood-for-log-linear-models)

$p_\theta(Y_t = y|X) = \frac{\alpha_t(Y_t = y) \beta_t(Y_t=y)}{Z_\theta(X)}$

I am not sure about $\alpha_t(y_t)$ being equal to $\alpha_t(y|X)$. Not sure of this is correct, but it might help someone.

[1](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/csutton/publications/crftut-fnt.pdf): *Sutton, C., & McCallum, A. (2012). An introduction to conditional random fields. Foundations and Trends in Machine Learning, 4(4), 267-373.*